# Parallelizing a code across CPU cores that iterates over a nested dictionary of a total 700K entries

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, parallel-processing, nested-for-loop

I have the following code:

```
for key in test_large_images.keys():
    test_large_images[key]['avg_prob'] = 0
    sum = 0
    for value in test_large_images[key]['pred_probability']:
        print(test_large_images[key]['pred'])
        print(type(test_large_images[key]['pred'] ))
        if test_large_images[key]['pred'] == 1:
            sum += value
    test_large_images[key]['avg_prob'] = sum/len(test_large_images[key]['pred_probability'])
```

and it is a dictionary of 359 large images that each could have between 200 to 8000 smaller images which I call patches. The `test_large_images` is a dictionary of inferences on the smaller images which also have prediction probability, large image name, patch name, etc for each patch. My goal is to find the average probability of the larger image based on the prediction probability of smaller patches prediction probabilities inside that image. When I run this loop on a smaller dataset (45K patches) for which I have saved its inferences in a `pkl` file, it runs very fast. But, it's been more than 130 minutes that this script has been running as you can see in Jupyter Notebook remotely on VSCode Remote (with a local client on Mac).

Is there a way I can take advantage of the 24 CPU cores I have to accelerate this nested dictionary computation?

[image]

Comment: Why is your test condition `test_large_images[key]['pred']==1` inside the `'pred_probability` loop? If you take it out then you have a simpler calculation.

Comment: @PeterK that is a necessary part of my computation. I need it.

Comment: Why is that taking so long? Looks like it should take at most a few seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't use `sum` as a variable name, since it's a built in function.
2. The line `test_large_images[key]['avg_prob'] = 0` is not needed.
3. PeterK is correct that your condition doesn't need to be calculated every time in the inner for loop.
4. Why are we printing these repeatedly, or was that just for testing?

```py
for key in test_large_images.keys():
    add = 0
    condition = test_large_images[key]['pred'] == 1 # This is what PeterK means by take it out (of the loop).
    for value in test_large_images[key]['pred_probability']:
        # print(test_large_images[key]['pred'])
        # print(type(test_large_images[key]['pred']))
        if condition:
            add += value
    test_large_images[key]['avg_prob'] = add/len(test_large_images[key]['pred_probability'])
```

Your code could be simplified to:

```
for key in test_large_images.keys():
    condition = test_large_images[key]['pred'] == 1
    num = sum(x for x in test_large_images[key]['pred_probability'] if condition)
    denom = len(test_large_images[key]['pred_probability'])
    test_large_images[key]['avg_prob'] = num/denom
```

Based off of feedback and some additional optimization:

```
for key in test_large_images.keys():
    if test_large_images[key]['pred'] != 1:
        test_large_images[key]['avg_prob'] = 0
        continue
    values = test_large_images[key]['pred_probability']
    test_large_images[key]['avg_prob'] = sum(values)/len(values)
```

Here's two different types of averaging (and I am most interested in taking the average of probabilities only over the number of entries for which the prediction was 1). I call that `avg_prob_pos`

```
for key in progress_bar(test_large_images.keys()):
    condition = test_large_images[key]['pred'] == 1
    num = sum(x for x in test_large_images[key]['pred_probability'] if condition)
    denom = len(test_large_images[key]['pred_probability'])
    count = sum(x for x in test_large_images[key]['pred'] if condition)
    if count != 0:
        test_large_images[key]['avg_prob_pos'] = num/count
    test_large_images[key]['avg_prob'] = num/denom
    
    percentage = test_large_images[key]['pred'].count(1)/len(test_large_images[key]['pred'])
    test_large_images[key]['percentage'] = percentage
```

Comment: If I loaded the dict into a pandas dataframe, I'd know how to parallelize it fairly easily...

Comment: or even faster, `if test_large_images[key]['pred'] != 1:`, `test_large_images[key]['avg_prob'] = 0`, `continue`.

Comment: @BeRT2me thank you, how would you change the denom if you only want to consider the ones that had the condition==1? I want to only divide it by number of entries for which pred==1? (instead of `denom = len(test_large_images[key]['pred_probability'])` all entries)

Comment: @MonaJalal Similar to num: `len([x for x in test_large_images[key]['pred_probability'] if condition])`

Comment: But at that point it'd best to pull that inner list out once, and and take the sum/len of it.

Comment: @BeRT2me I think it will be `count = sum(x for x in test_large_images[key]['pred'] if condition)`

Comment: @PeterK I added a third option~

Comment: @BeRT2me and Peter it was extremely fast thanks a zillion. Also, there's a chance remote VSCode was dead due to spotty wifi. I converted it to Python script.

Comment: I would just iterate over values directly in this case instead of keys:
`for obj in test_large_images.values(): obj['avg_prob'] = 0 if not obj['pred'] else statistics.mean(obj['pred_probability'])`